# Magento and mandrill smtp headers

Tags: magento2, mandrill

I am using Mandrill as a SMTP.

It is successfully connected to Magento 2.

My question :

Is it possible to use Mandrill's custom header references  through Magento Email Templates.

For example, I have created custom templates in Mandrill that can be called upon by a customized field in the email header.

Usually it can be added the same way as the reply-to field.

I want to use the following functionality below:

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582117-How-to-Use-SMTP-Headers-to-Customize-Your-M...

Can I add in the header template :

```
<?php
$headers = $this->getHeaders();
$headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-Template', 'template_name');
?>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own plugin for Magento (as it was done in the mageplaza/magento-2-smtp extension, they have shared their experience [here](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/blob/master/Mail/Transport.php)) that will help you to rewrite the send mail function `sendMessage ()` through the `aroundSendMessage ()` function. In this case you can write headers on your own depend on the message.

How to create a plugin for Magento 2 you can find at Magento official documentation: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html